# new IP for ubuntu VPS can't ping outside the box / ssh hangs

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vps

my VPS provider just changed my VPS' IP, everything is working (like the webserver) but I have two problems

1. when I login via SSH after I type the user the console hangs for
   about 10 seconds before prompting the password request, also this
   happens when I login with SFTP and at every file transfer.
2. I can't ping domains/IPs outside the box, apache benchmarks won't work anymore.

I notice that in /etc/network/interfaces I still have an interface with the old IP along with the new one, could it be that the system tries to use the first one (old one) and then go to the second one?

I tried to delete it and restart networking but its still there. I know very little about networking in VPSes, is it even something I can do or it can be controlled only from the host machine?